# Integrate Solr with Cassandra in windows

Tags: solr, configuration, cassandra, integration

I am trying to integrate Solr with Cassandra in windows. I have followed following links:
[BigDataTutor](http://bigdatatutor.blogspot.qa/2014/08/solr-cassandra-integaration-without.html) ,  [DataStex](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchConfDataHand.html)

I am confused where to copy data-config.xml, schema.xml and solrconfig.xml. The datastex documentation is not clear. Kindly assist me.

http://bigdatatutor.blogspot.qa/2014/08/solr-cassandra-integaration-without.html

Comment: Same here, also confused about those config files. I don't know where they should go